# WinJS Custom Control Events "invalid argument"

Tags: javascript, dom-events, winjs

I'm creating a custom WinJS control with an event listener. For simplicity, this example should fire an event whenever it is tapped.

This is created with the markup:

```
<div class="alphaNavBar" data-win-control="MobMan.Controls.AlphaNavBar"></div>
```

The control is implemented here. It throws an "invalid argument" exception at the `dispatchEvent(...)` line.

```
(function () {
    var alphaNavBar = WinJS.Class.define(function (el, options) {
        // Create control
        var self = this;
        this._element = el || document.createElement("div");
        this._element.winControl = this;

        this._element.innerText = "Hello World!";
        this._selection = false;

        // Listen for tap
        this._element.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", function (evt) {
            // Toggle selection
            self._selection = !self._selection;

            // Selection changed, fire event
            // Invalid argument here
            self._element.dispatchEvent("mySelectionChanged", { selection: self._selection });
            // Invalid argument here
        });
    });

    // Add to global namespace
    WinJS.Namespace.define("MobMan.Controls", {
        AlphaNavBar: alphaNavBar
    });
    
    // Mixin event properties
    WinJS.Class.mix(MobMan.Controls.AlphaNavBar, WinJS.Utilities.createEventProperties("mySelectionChanged"), WinJS.UI.DOMEventMixin);
})();
```

This event is listened to by:

```
var alphaNavBar = document.querySelector(".alphaNavBar");
alphaNavBar.addEventListener("mySelectionChanged", function (evt) {
    // Should fire when alphaNavBar is tapped
    debugger;
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Offhand your code looks fine. WinJS is in your project as source, so you should be able to step directly into DOMEventMixin.displatchEventin the debugger and see more specifically where the exception is coming from.

Comment: @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT stepping inside the dispatchEvent(...) call throws the error immediately, it doesn't go to any line that might be causing the problem. Stepping inside after the error occurs takes me to `window.__BROWSERTOOLS_CONSOLE_SAFEFUNC(fn, safeAssert)`. Stepping into anything there goes nowhere and eventually just crashes the debugger and app.

Comment: Try calling self.dispatchEvent rather than self._element.dispatchEvent. The latter is calling the DOM API directly, the former is going through the method in the WinJS mixin--I should have noticed that distinction before. And if it still crashes ad doesn't let you step in via the debugger, open the WinJS base.js file directly (under References in Solution Explorer of VS) and set a breakpoint on DOMEventMixin.dispatchEvent.

Comment: Changing it to self.dispatchEvent(...) and this.dispatchEvent(...) both yield the same invalid argument error I've been getting. I looked into base.js and put a breakpoint in every dispatchEvent(...) function I could find, but the error is still thrown before any breakpoints are triggered.

Comment: Strange. Any chance you can put a repro sample somewhere so I can step through directly?

Comment: What is a good way of doing that? I can't get any WinJS to run on JSFiddle, which is usually my go to in these situations. Should I just put a zip somewhere? All the code is shown, I don't think it's missing anything.

Comment: Yes, just put a .zip somewhere. It saves me the trouble of having to create a project, an HTML file, etc.

Comment: I was able to create an empty project with it and upload it here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/xz2bgubjpcco3v0/AlphaNavBar.zip?dl=0). Sorry for the delay Windows 10 was screwing with my project. File > New Project... Run would fail! It was trying to make a Windows 10 app which wasn't working, so I had to change the project type a bit, but the code is the same. I'm getting the same error here, so let me know if you get a different outcome. Thanks for your help with this by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ec561c8-ca91-439f-932a-782f0124b63b/w81html-winjs-custom-control-events-invalid-argument?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required) as well and got an answer modifying the event dispatch like so:

```
// Listen for tap
this._element.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", function (evt) {
    // Toggle selection
    this._selection = !this._selection;

    // Create the event.
    var _event = document.createEvent('customevent');

    // Define that the event name is 'mySelectionChanged' and pass details.
    _event.initCustomEvent('mySelectionChanged', true, true, { selection: this._selection });

    // Selection changed, fire event
    this.dispatchEvent(_event);
});
```

This was able to trigger the event correctly for me. Still not sure what I was doing wrong before, but it is fixed now.